# show confirm dialog on click ionic toggle button

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, toggle, angularjs-ng-change

i have a toggle linked  with $scope.checked, when I Click on the toggle button I want to show a confirm dialog before changing toggle value.
How can i do it ?
HTML :

```
<ion-toggle ng-model="settings_option" toggle-class="toggle-calm"     **ng-change="showConfirm(settings_option)"** ng-checked="settings_option">
Setting Options
</ion-toggle>
```

JS:

```
$rootScope.showConfirm = function(newVal) {
    if(newVal == true){
        console.log("start false !!!")
        var confirmPopup = $ionicPopup.confirm({
         title: 'Mode configuration',
         template: 'voulez-vous vraiment activer cette option?'
       });

       confirmPopup.then(function(res) {
        console.log("RES :: "+res);
         if(res) {
           window.localStorage.setItem("settings_option", "true");
           $rootScope.settings_option = false;
         } else {
           console.log($rootScope.settings_option);
           $rootScope.settings_option = false;
           console.log($rootScope.settings_option);
         }
       });
    }
    else{
        window.localStorage.setItem("settings_option", "false");
       $rootScope.settings_option = false;
    }

 }
```

Comment: please show us the relevant parts of your code, what you have already tried so we can help you.

Comment: ok I edited my Post !

Comment: Please use updated answer, comment if there is any problem.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<li class="item item-toggle">
 Setting Options
 <label class="toggle toggle-calm">
   <input type="checkbox" ng-model="settings_option" ng-change="showConfirm(settings_option)" ng-true-value="yes" ng-false-value="no">
   <div class="track">
     <div class="handle"></div>
   </div>
 </label>
</li>
```

controller

```
$rootScope.showConfirm = function(newVal) {
if(newVal == "yes"){
    console.log("start false !!!")
    var confirmPopup = $ionicPopup.confirm({
     title: 'Mode configuration',
     template: 'voulez-vous vraiment activer cette option?'
   });

   confirmPopup.then(function(res) {
    console.log("RES :: "+res);
     if(res) {
       window.localStorage.setItem("settings_option", "yes");
       $rootScope.settings_option = "yes";
     } else {
       console.log($rootScope.settings_option);
       $rootScope.settings_option = "no";
       console.log($rootScope.settings_option);
     }
   });
}
else{
    window.localStorage.setItem("settings_option", "no");
   $rootScope.settings_option = "no";
  }
 }
```

Comment: not working, it still returns a boolean value not a string !

Comment: I add this line "console.log(newVal);" in the biginning of the function, I get true (Boolean) not "true" (String)

Comment: try "yes" and "no" values

Comment: i get this error message : Expected constant expression for `ngTrueValue`, but saw `yes`.

Comment: use `ng-init="settings_option='yes'"` or `ng-init="settings_option='no'"`

Comment: the error is gone after adding quotations ng-true-value="'yes'", but I still can't set toggle to no when Click Cancel in the confirm Dialog :/